# How to I save each letter as an independent variable in python?

Tags: python

So basically what I'm doing is I was making a password-guesser thing where you input a password, and I use a system to crack it! I don't think people realize how easy their passwords are, so I thought this would be cool. Here's the code.

```
# main.py
lower = ["a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,,w,x,y,z"]
upper = ["A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M"]

password = input("Please enter a password! ")
for i in range(len(password)):
  print(password[i])
```

So I have it print every letter that's in the password, but how do I save them as variables so I can check if they equal any of the letters?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your issue? What system?

Comment: For clarification I'm just not sure what to try.

Comment: why are you storing lower and upper as strings inside lists?

Comment: If you have something variable length, you almost always want to use a list (or a dict), which is exactly how you deal with “variable variables”

Comment: and if someone enters their password directly, what exactly are you cracking?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a list with all the letters of the string.

```py
password = "abc123"
letters_of_password = [char for char in password if char.isalpha()]
print(letters_of_password)
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

If you really want to create variable for each letter (I don't know why you would want that...), you can do the following. But I don't recommend that because you will manipulate values that aren't supposed to be changed by the user but by python itself.

```py
password = "abc123"
locals().update({char: char for char in password if char.isalpha()})
print(a, b, c)
# a b c
```

Also, you don't need `lower` and `upper` variable, just use `string`:

```py
import string

print(string.ascii_letters)
# abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
print(string.ascii_lowercase)
# abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
print(string.ascii_uppercase)
# ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: Baically what I want to do it take the input, and separate all the letters as there own variables.

Comment: I added the `locals()` stuff, is that what you want?